# Center and pin to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

Hey all, quick question regarding CSS. On [my website](http://chigstuff.com/), I'd like it if the navbar was centered, and pinned to the bottom of the header (the bottom of the gradient). I cannot figure out how to do this.

The site doesn't support IE... Yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your header to a relative position and your nav to absolute instead of relative.

Comment: That moved the nav down to the bottom, but now I gotta center them. The float: left in `nav li` is what is messing it up, but if I get rid of that, the list goes back to being vertical.

Comment: @Chiggins: For the 'header' tag use some float clearing techniques, like clearfix, etc. What I tend to do is, see my answer. I'm goona edit it now

Answer (score 1):

Make your 'header' tag as a relative position. Then make the 'nav' tag as an absolute position, and do 'bottom: 0' to it. All in your CSS. And it should work.
Then move it left or/and right, using the 'left' and 'right' rules in css.

Like this:

```
header {
position: relative;
zoom: 1; /*needed to clear float in IE*/
}

header:after {
clear: both;
display: block;
content: " ";
visibility: hidden;
height: 0;
}

nav {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```